# Clojure unsigned 64-bit integers

Tags: clojure

How do I define an **unsigned** `long` in Clojure? (Or are there arbitrary size integers in the standard library, e.g. some sort of *BigInt* or *BigNum*?)

I'd only use it in bitwise operations, so technically the numeric value represented by the binary data is not so important, but I'd still like numbers >2<sup>63</sup> to be displayed as positive integers when I `println` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just writing a custom function that converts your `long` into a String with the appropriate unsigned representation.

Something like:

```
(defn long-str [x] 
     (if (> x 0) 
       (str x)
       (str (+ (bigint x) 18446744073709551616N))))

(long-str -1)
=> "18446744073709551615"
```

Comment: Or I could just have my methods return `bigint` and let the user do the conversion. Thanks, I didn't know about `bigint`.